# Sorry to ask such a dumb one, but what is this?

Tags: javascript

Recently I came upon a weird line in a [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)(Second answer, couldn't find a way to link directly to the answer).
This is it:

```
reverse = !reverse ? 1 : -1;
```

Well, I guess specifically the use of `boolean ? option : option;`

This looks like legitimately nothing I have encountered so far. I cannot find it in google! Please explain what this is, what is the syntax and how to use it, because I really want to know what this is, since it looks like some advanced smart thing...

Is that a if-else statement? Thanks for reading this and answering! :D

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Googling `?` is, admittedly, kind of difficult. But it's an operator, so try [Javascript operators](https://www.google.com/#q=Javascript+operators) and you would have probably found what you are looking for. Even then it's kind of buried. The first two results I got didn't even have it (but that's W3Schools for you). The third (also W3Schools, but their reference page - does have it). [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) has it, but it's pretty buried in the "special" operators section.

Comment: @MattBurland Thanks, my question was already answered and marked as a dublicate :( Thanks anyway!

Comment: @TheSuperCuber: I know it's answered already, I was trying to suggest some better ways to find the answer because it is genuinely difficult to google `?` and get anything meaning full as a result. It's even difficult to do on StackOverflow, it's an edge case as far as searching goes. Either way, you really need a better title for your question.

Answer (score 5):

It's a ternary (conditional) expression:

```
var result = condition ? "true result" : "false result";
```

Example:

```
// since 1 is less than 2 result = "It's less!"
var result = 1 < 2 ? "It's less!" : "It's more!";
```

Comment: Also tested `alert(1<2 ? "Hi" : "Bye");` and it worked. Thanks everyone, because I totally had no clue! :D

Answer (score 1):

The `? :` is the [**ternary operator**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). It was invented to simplify stuff like this:

```
if (booleanExpression) {
    var x = expression1;
} else {
    var x = expression2;
}
```

So the above would become:

```
var x = booleanExpression ? expression1: expression2;
```

They are equivalent but using the ternary operator is a bit more concise. I've mostly seen this used for conditional assignment or just making an `if-else` clause more compact/require fewer keystrokes. In the example you gave, I would imagine it is used for conditionally reversing some collection based on an argument or flag provided to the module.

Comment: It should be `booleanExpression ? expression1 : expression2`. The conditional operator can't have statements for its true and false branches. For example, you can't do `true ? var x = 1; var x = -1;`. That's invalid syntax.

Comment: @AaditMShah Yes you can, but you should do `true ? var x=1*:* var x=-1;`

Comment: @TheSuperCuber __No. You can't.__ Press `Ctrl + Shift + I` and paste  `true ? var x = 1; var x = -1;` into the console. It will give you a syntax error.

Comment: @AaditMShah You still make the same mistake, look at my code, i highlighted your mistake with **. you should use `:` between the statements, but not `;`

Comment: @TheSuperCuber It's still a syntax error. Yes, I concede I made a typo when I used a semicolon instead of a colon. However, the argument was still valid. The conditional operator is an operator (i.e. it is an expression). An expression cannot have a statement within it. Hence `true ? var x = 1 : var x = -1;` is still a syntax error.

Comment: @AaditMShah try the same without var, worked for me. I dont know what is going on. :D

Comment: @TheSuperCuber Of course it did. It's because `x = 1` is an expression. However, `var x = 1` is a statement. Why am I having such a stupid discussion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72778/discussion-between-the-supercuber-and-aadit-m-shah).

Comment: @TheSuperCuber Let's not.

Comment: @AaditMShah Well then I'll just copy what I've said there:
I have no idea, could you wait a second while I'm testing that with an .html document? 
Ill do the following: true ? `alert("Hi") : alert("Bye"); `
Also, gonna try that in the console now.
Worked in the console.
Watcha say?